# How to replace cell values by blank if cells are matched

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to compare values of two cells. If cell values are equal, they will be replaced by a blank, how can I write the formatting code to do this?

In my case, I will compare cell E and G. In the diagram, E4 and G4 values are same. So, these values will need to be removed and replaced by 0.

[image: cells]

Comment: How are those cells populated?

Comment: These values(parameter values) are calculated from another sheets(for 20 different data groups)

Comment: What are the formula in those cells, you will need to combine the formula to see if they equal and if so put 0.

Comment: Data in row 2 are the parameter from sheet d1,Data in row 3 are the parameter from sheet d2, and so on. How can I write the code to compare the values with all other sheets? sorry for being lame, I so not have much experience of working with excel

Comment: there is not enough information to help you.  please see [mcve], simplify the question.  Give as small test data set that represents your data including the source data and expected output.

Comment: I tried to clear raw data instead of final result. This is the link: https://superuser.com/q/1577002/1198380  and I could clear/delete raw data which ultimately deleted the result if they are matched